# Writing in Traditional Ksav Ashuris (Sofer Script)

Tags: sefer-torah, safrus, torah-writing

I was wondering if there is any instructional video or guide online showing how to form all the letters of the Hebrew alphabet in the traditional [Ksav Ashuris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashuri_alphabet) script.

Please note that my motives for learning how to write this way is most certainly *not* so I can write a Sefer Torah, but because I do English calligraphy for a hobby and I want to learn to do Ksav Ashuris, as it is kind of like Hebrew calligraphy.

As for nusach, it would be preferable if the video or guide showed how to write the letters according to the Ari Zal, but Beis Yosef or even Alter Rebbe is also fine (especially Alter Rebbe).

Comment: I don't understand the reasoning for the 2 (so far) VTC's. My wedding invitations were written by a calligrapher in Sefardi style Ktav Ashurit. It's so nice that I framed it, and I think I have the original "press" somewhere. Now, if somehow I can locate the calligrapher, so that I can ask her. I hope that she hasn't "written off" doing this job, LOL.

Comment: Note using Ashruit script for personal uses is Halachically problematic https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A8%D7%A4%D7%93

Comment: @DoubleAA - I wanted to write out verses of Scripture in Hebrew using the Ashuri alphabet. So even though it would be a personal reason it would not be something not holy.

Comment: @ezra you would need sirtut then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This site](http://www.hasoferet.com/learning-hebrew-calligraphy/) offers some general ideas on where to find lessosn and books, etc. as well as equipment suggestions. The site recommends  Izzy Pludwinski’s [Mastering Hebrew Calligraphy](http://impwriter.com/Mastering_Hebrew_Calligraphy.html) as a starter as well as thorough book on the art of Hebrew calligraphy.

[This course](http://mastery.webyeshiva.org/safrut-certification/) is an online course in safrut. Granted, that isn't your goal according to what you stated. However, while learning the technique of safrut, you will obviously learn how to write the letters. At the end of the course, besides doing calligraphy, you will have the option of writing mezuzot and tefillin.

(If you do this, contact me. I'm ready to buy one from you :-)

Comment: I do not support the endeavors of the website you have provided, so it is of no use to me. However, the book you linked seems like a good starting point.

Comment: @EzraHoerster Can you explain why?

Comment: the owner of the site is a woman sofer which I believe is not kosher or a good practice. (Note that the website is called "Hasoferet," a woman scribe)

Comment: I see. Granted, I didn't view the entire page in depth. However, as far as I can tell, what would be wrong with a woman offering suggestions or writing an article on safrut, which is what the author seems to be doing? Does it matter if the author herself happens to be a soferet? Obviously, you're not having a problem with the book that she recommended. So it was of SOME use to you, not "no use".

Comment: I've added an additional resource that may be more reliable. I know that there are some online resources, as well. Have to research a bit. Shabbat Shalom.

Comment: @ezra most hold women can write megillat Esther and all hold she can write the other megillot and neviim. What's wrong with trusting her skills? If only more women wrote neviim in their spare time, more shuls would have them available! The current situation is embarrassing honestly.

Comment: @EzraHoerster Of course, more importantly, finding books to read from her site doesn't actually support her in any way and will in fact be highly useful to you. But that's a side point.

Comment: @DoubleAA - I can tell you see my convictions as strange, but that is OK. I understand it does not directly help her but to me it is like trusting a Christian website...it's not bad really it's just not advised and some do not look at them at all.

Comment: @EzraHoerster You realize that she's allowed to write all parts of Tanakh? She's not performing any Issur. Comparing this to Christianity is absurd. Again, if only we had women who knew how to write in order to have more Nevi'im available. The men it seems don't have the time to write too many of them.